# Adjusting toDate(now()) for non-GMT time zone

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language, google-sheets-query

I know that, according to [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage?csw=1#scalar_functions), `now()` gives datetime in GMT. I want to get the date from that with `toDate()`, but everything in my sheet and what I'm comparing to it is in EDT, so I need to subtract 4 hours from GMT.

I can't seem to figure out how to subtract 4 hours from `now()` before grabbing the date then comparing.

The query is basically

```
=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:Z,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H where D matches 'Some Text' and A >= toDate(now())",1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First be sure that the spreadsheet timezone setting is EDT:
  File > Spreadsheet settings...

Then you could use the built-in function `NOW()`. In contrast with the scalar function `now()` of Query Language, it returns a date-time value in the timezone of the spreadsheet.

Then use `TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy-mm-dd")` to get the date on the required format and use it after the `date` keyword.

The final formula is

`=QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:Z,"select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H where D matches 'Some Text' and A >= date '"&TEXT(NOW(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)`